# how can i send file from s3 into the user in django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

i have a website , this website you can use it to upload a file.

after that the users will be able to download what you have uploaded in that website.

i upload a file , and this file is getting saved inside a bucket in AWS-S3.

now how can i read that file from the bucket and send it to the user ?

this is my function for donwloading :

```py
class Download(View):
    def get(self, request):
        try:
            if request.session["language"] == "en":
                the_path_of_templates = "website/en/"
            else:
                the_path_of_templates = "website/ar/"
        except:
            the_path_of_templates = "website/en/"

        #########################################################
        # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # # #
        #########################################################

        try:
            the_file = KarafetaProduct.objects.all()[0]
            
            with open(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, str(the_file.file)), "rb") as file:
                file_data = file.read()

            response = HttpResponse(file_data, content_type='application/vnd.microsoft.portable-executable')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(str(the_file.name))

            return response
        except:
            return render(request=request, template_name=f"{the_path_of_templates}home.html")
```

this is the link of the file in s3 :

> karafeta-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com\Python-3.11.5_3_q9ZN0gC.exe

Comment: Can you show the `KarafetaProduct` model class? Is the field called `file` a FileField? If so, is there an issue with you sending a signed url from S3 for the user to download from their side? rather than sending the file in the response? That is the usual way to do this.

Comment: @Arun T yes, it is a FileField.

Comment: @Arun T ...  to be honest i could not redirect the user to the s3 link, every time it gives me an error

Comment: how can i send the signed url from S3 ?

Comment: i do not want it to be fixed url in the html because the file name is being changed everytime

Comment: The url will be generated behind the scenes when you use `.url` on that field in your views. It will be generated based on the file_path/name stored in that database field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming your model to be similar to this

```
class KarafetaProduct(Base):
    file = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads/", blank=True, null=True)
```

If its a FileField, you can generate the signed url from S3 and send that in the response like below

```
the_file = KarafetaProduct.objects.all()[0]
print(the_file.file.url)  ---> This will give the signed url to download the file from S3 and your FE application can use this url to start the download in browser.
```

You can then inject this as per your need in your response

Comment: thanks for your help , it worked ..... but now if the file is an image when i redirect the file url it is being opened in the browser not being downloaded

Comment: that is simple. Just put `download` in your html a tag. Example: `<a href="/url/from/s3" download></a>`

Comment: If the answer helped you, do accept the answer. Thanks :)

Comment: off course it helped me .. but i did not get how to download an image not show it ... for that i am waiting for better answer if there is a one . if it is not then i will accept yours

Comment: did you try my comment above?

Comment: yes i did , but the problem is that the button when it is getting clicked it takes you into view function and that function check if you are signed in or not if not you have to log in . the second problem is that the URL is not fixed

Comment: That should be another question in itself. But I think you should handle it differently based on a button click, redirect to a new url and then handle this there. That could be one of the many ways to solve this.